# Unexpected Application Error! Cannot destructure property 'loading' of '(0 , react_redux__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.useSelector) as it is undefined

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redux-toolkit

I'm new to React. I'm trying to develop a login system using django (djoser) in the backend and react for the frontend.
However, whenever i run the npm server and go to the login page i see the following error:

> Unexpected Application Error!
> Cannot destructure property 'loading' of '(0 , react_redux__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.useSelector)(...)' as it is undefined.
> TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'loading' of '(0 , react_redux__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.useSelector)(...)' as it is undefined.

here are the files I think are relevant for this case:

- login.js

```
import { useForm  } from 'react-hook-form'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { userLoggin } from '../features/auth/authActions';
 



const Login = () => {
    
    const { loading, userInfo, error } = useSelector((state) => state.user)
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm()
    const navigate = useNavigate()

    useEffect(() => {
        if (userInfo) {
            navigate ('/user-profile')
        }
    }, [navigate, userInfo]
    )

    const submitForm = (data) => {
        dispatch(userLoggin(data))
    }

    return (
        <form className="mb-3" onSubmit={handleSubmit(submitForm)}>
            {error && <h3>{error}</h3>}
            <div className='form-group'>
                <label htmlFor='email'>Email</label>
                <input
                    type='email'
                    className='form-input'
                    {...register('email')}
                    required
                />
            </div>
            <div className='form-group'>
                <label htmlFor='password'>Password</label>
                <input
                    type='password'
                    className='form-input'
                    {...register('password')}
                    required
                />
            </div>
            <button 
                type='submit'
                className='button'
                 
            >
                {loading ? <h3>loading...</h3> : 'Login'}
            </button>
        </form>
    )
};

export default Login;
```

- authaction.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';


const backendURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'
export const userLoggin = createAsyncThunk(
    'auth/login',
    async ({email, password }, [rejectWithValue]) => {
        try {
            const config = {
                headers : {
                    'Content-Type': 'applicatiom/json',
                },
            }
            const { data } = await axios.post(
                `${backendURL}/auth/jwt/create/`,
                { email, password },
                config
            )
            localStorage.setItem('userToken', data.userToken)
            return data
        } catch (error) {
            if (error.response && error.response.data.message) {
                return rejectWithValue (error.response.message)
            }
            else {
                return rejectWithValue (error.message)
            }
        }
    }
)
```

- authslice.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import  { userLoggin } from "./authActions";

const userToken = localStorage.getItem('userToken')
    ? localStorage.getItem('userToken')
    : null

const initialState = {
    loading: false,
    userInfo: {},
    userToken,
    error: null,
    success: false,
}

const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'auth',
    initialState,
    reducers: {},
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        //user login
        builder
            .addCase(userLoggin.pending, (state) => {
                state.loading = true
                state.error = null
            })
            .addCase(userLoggin.fulfilled, (state, {payload}) => {
                state.loading = false
                state.userInfo = payload
                state.userToken = payload.userToken
           })
            .addCase(userLoggin.rejected, (state, action) => {
                state.loading = false
                state.error =  action.payload
        })
    }
})

export default authSlice.reducer
```

store.js

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import authReducer from '../features/auth/authSlice';

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        auth: authReducer,
    }
})

export default store
```

In fact i didn't try many as i said I'm new to react.

Comment: Try rerunning `npm install` to install the project dependencies. If you have somehow missed adding `react-redux` as a dependency then now's the time to add it with `npm instal react-redux` and then rebuild your project for django deployment.

Comment: thank you for your reply. but in fact the problem was caused by a bad import. i imported BrowserRouter instead of createbrowserRouter. so when i tried to use BrowserRouter instaed of createBrowserrouter in the CreateRouteFromElement method, it throws me an error. but when i used createBrowserRouter, everything went fine.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your reply. but in fact the problem was caused by a bad import. i imported BrowserRouter instead of createbrowserRouter. so when i tried to use BrowserRouter instaed of createBrowserrouter in the CreateRouteFromElement method, it throws me an error. but when i used createBrowserRouter, everything went fine

Comment: Best to update your original question with the answer rather than provide a new answer here